# how to make my series of axes as normal as highercharts width?

Tags: graph, highcharts, data-visualization, axes, graph-visualization

how to make my graph looks normal. I searched but I didn't find any relevant result. please help me out. [my graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1wwg.png)

how can I make the data represent line's to normal width as they are so "thin" and also please tell me how to remove "0%" at middle of "bar"

I think because of this data my graph not showing properly. But how should pass data. Here below you can see my data

---

```json
categories: [
  'Energy',
  'Real Estate',
  'Information Technology',
  'Financials',
  'Healthcare',
  'Consumer Discretionary',
  'Materials',
  'Communication Services',
  'Industrials',
  'Consumer Staples',
  'Utilities',
],
series: [{
    name: 'Energy',
    data: [59.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    color: '#385723',
    width: 6,
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#385723',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Real Estate',
    data: [0, 56.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    color: '#385723',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#385723',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Information Technology',
    data: [0, 0, 37.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    color: '#548235',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#548235',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Financials',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 35.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    color: '#548235',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#548235',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Healthcare',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 26.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    color: '#548235',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#548235',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Consumer Discretionary',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    color: '#548235',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#548235',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Materials',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13.7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    color: '#548235',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#548235',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Communication Services',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.8, 0, 0, 0],
    color: '#A9D18E',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#A9D18E',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Industrials',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.4, 0, 0],
    color: '#C5E0B4',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#C5E0B4',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Consumer Staples',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.2, 0],
    color: '#F8CBAD',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#F8CBAD',
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Utilities',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.5],
    color: '#F4B183',
    dataLabels: {
      color: '#F4B183',
    },
  },
],
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean, to me the graph looks normal. How do you want it to look? If you don't want values on the left of the Y axis, you can't have negative values. Maybe draw another chart to show how you think it should look.

Comment: @AndyGee thanks for responding
please say me how to make my series to normal width as you saw in pic the data represented lines are so "thin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable `grouping`:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        grouping: false
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/osvje9uz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.grouping

Comment: thank you very much @ppotaczek sir for your help. How can remove "0" at middle of graph without removing  dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    format: '{y} %',
                     }

Comment: Hi @srinivas, I am glad that I could help. I will answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71671846/how-to-remove-0-at-middle-of-graph