# how to remove "0%" at middle of graph?

Tags: graph, highcharts, graph-visualization, react-graph-vis

I tried "stacking" and "styles" in plotOptions to remove 0% in the middle of my graph. please see my "codepen" example to understand my problem and help me out.

[my graph code](https://codepen.io/srinivas33333/pen/oNpeNOr)

```
 plotOptions: {
                            bar: {
                              stackings: 'normal',
                              dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '{y} %',
                              },
                              marker: {
                                enabled: false,
                              },
                            },
                            series: {
                              grouping: false,
                            },
                          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `formatter` function and show data-labels only with different value than 0:

```
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      ...,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.y !== 0) {
            return this.y + ' %';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t98hzdbx/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.formatter